# Manage Multiple View Types - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using [this](https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-MultipleViewTypesAdapter) library to display mutiple types of views inside a RecyclerView .

Here I am using EnumMapBindAdapter to display userposts list .

I have 4 DataBinder classes ,each binder has a list of size 3 (size may change depending on the 
user posts ) . I have problem with  getEnumFromPosition() ,According to my assumptions number of executions of getEnumFromPosition() method should be equal to number of binders (4) . But it is not happening .I have total 4 binders and I assume getEnumFromPosition() method should execute 4 times only (0,1,2,3) ,but executions are being excedeed . My assumption may be wrong ,If I am wrong then how can 
I manage 4 binders inside getEnumFromPosition() for different positions . If I put else section inside getEnumFromPosition() method then it will return a single view when position exceeds .

**Here is the code of SampleEnumMapAdapter.java**

```
 public class SampleEnumMapAdapter extends EnumMapBindAdapter<SampleEnumMapAdapter.SampleViewType> {

    enum SampleViewType{
        TEXT,IMAGE_AND_TEXT, AUDIO_AND_TEXT, VIDEO_AND_TEXT
    }

    public SampleEnumMapAdapter(){
        putBinder(SampleViewType.TEXT, new TextBinder(this));
        putBinder(SampleViewType.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, new ImageAndTextBinder(this));
        putBinder(SampleViewType.AUDIO_AND_TEXT, new AudioAndTextBinder(this));
        putBinder(SampleViewType.VIDEO_AND_TEXT, new VideoAndTextBinder(this));
    }

    public void setData(List<TextData> dataSetText ,List<ImageAndTextData> dataSetTextAndImage ,List<AudioAndTextData> dataSetTextAndAudio ,List<VideoAndTextData> dataSetTextAndVideo ) {
        ((TextBinder) getDataBinder(SampleViewType.TEXT)).addAll(dataSetText);
        ((ImageAndTextBinder) getDataBinder(SampleViewType.IMAGE_AND_TEXT)).addAll(dataSetTextAndImage);
        ((AudioAndTextBinder) getDataBinder(SampleViewType.AUDIO_AND_TEXT)).addAll(dataSetTextAndAudio);
        ((VideoAndTextBinder) getDataBinder(SampleViewType.VIDEO_AND_TEXT)).addAll(dataSetTextAndVideo);
    }

    @Override
    public SampleViewType getEnumFromPosition(int position){
        if (position == 0) {
            return SampleViewType.TEXT;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return SampleViewType.IMAGE_AND_TEXT;
        } else if(position == 2){
            return SampleViewType.AUDIO_AND_TEXT;
        }else if(position == 3){
            return SampleViewType.VIDEO_AND_TEXT;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleViewType getEnumFromOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        return SampleViewType.values()[ordinal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on the similar problem earlier , But I configured RecyclerView Adapter manually ,I have not used any library for this . I am giving you a sample code here . This is a complete Multile View Type Adapter

```
    public class UserPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserPostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private List<UserPostsListItem> postlist;
    Context conetxt;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewClickListener mClickListener;
    private ItemViewClickListener itemViewClickListener;
    int count;

    public UserPostAdapter() {

    }

    public UserPostAdapter(Context conetxt, List<UserPostsListItem> postlist) {
        this.postlist = postlist;
        this.conetxt = conetxt;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.conetxt);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size = 0;
        if (postlist != null)
            size = postlist.size();
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewTypePosition =0;

        String attachment_type = postlist.get(position).getAttachment_type();

        switch (attachment_type){

            case "text":
                viewTypePosition = 0 ;
                break;
            case "image":
                viewTypePosition = 1 ;
                break;
            case "audio":
                viewTypePosition = 2 ;
                break;
            case "video":
                viewTypePosition = 3 ;
                break;
            default:
        }

        return viewTypePosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder videoViewHolder, final int position) {

        //Log.d("onBindViewHolder",Integer.toString(position));
        final UserPostsListItem item = postlist.get(position);

        switch (item.getAttachment_type()){
            case "audio":

                break;
            case "video":

                break;
            case "text":

                break;
            case "image":

                break;           
            default:
        }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public interface ItemViewClickListener {
        void onItemChildClicked(int position ,String type);
    }

    public void setItemViewClickListener (ItemViewClickListener viewClickListener) {
        itemViewClickListener = viewClickListener;
    }


    public List<UserPostsListItem> getUserPostsList() {
        return postlist;
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){

        Log.d("ViewType", Integer.toString(viewType));
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                View itemViewText = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userposts_listitem_text, viewGroup, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(itemViewText ,viewType);

            case 1:
                View itemViewTextImage = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userposts_listitem_textandimage, viewGroup, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(itemViewTextImage,viewType);

            case 2:
                View itemViewTextAudio = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userposts_listitem_audioandtext, viewGroup, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(itemViewTextAudio,viewType);

            case 3:
                View itemViewTextVideo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userposts_listitem_videoandtext, viewGroup, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(itemViewTextVideo,viewType);

            default:
        }

        return null;

    }

    public interface ViewClickListener {
        void onVideoClicked(int position,View v);
    }

    public List<UserPostsListItem> getVideoItems() {
        return postlist;
    }

    public void setViewClickListener (ViewClickListener viewClickListener) {
        mClickListener = viewClickListener;
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView attachment;
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
        ImageView audio;
        public PostViewHolder(View v,int viewtype) {
            super(v);
            switch (viewtype){
                //For Audio
                case 2:                    
                    break;                  
                //For Video
                case 3:                    
                    break;
                //For Text only
                case 0:
                    break;
                //For Image
                case 1:                    
                    break;                
                default:

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you James for your answer , But you are late . I have solved this problem .

Comment: @AndroidDev if you solved it already why isn't your solution posted here as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't manage binders by position, manage binders by type of data to be stored/shown at that position. Add a type field to SampleViewType and on every position match the type with its respective binder and load its respective data.

**Example for explanation :-**

You mainly need to change only one method inside your adapter. For the sake of explanation, let us assume you are inflating a List of data in your adapter. Let the list's name data.
Your method getEnumFromPosition() would look something like this :-

```
@Override
public SampleViewType getEnumFromPosition(int position){
    return data.get(position).getViewType();
}
```

In the above lines of code, data is your list and get method gets one of the object from the list. This object is of type SampleViewType. In your class SampleViewType you would need to create a data member called type which will hold the type of each object of your class SampleViewType and will have a getter function named getViewType(). This getViewType() function will return the type of that particular SampleViewType object, like SampleViewType.TEXT etc like you returned with respect to position.

You might need to create a separate class named SampleView and inflate your adapter with it, while your class SampleViewType will hold important information for all types of your SampleViews.

I hope this example explains you what I want to convey, in case of any confusion please do feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I am confused here ,Can you please include modified code (SampleEnumMapAdapter.java) in your answer , So that I can understand how can I do it ?

Comment: I am in the way right now ,I will implement your solution when I will reach at home .

Comment: Your hint is ok if I have only one list of items , what I will have to do when I have total 4 lists of items .

Comment: Combine them up into a single list and inflate by help of your adapter.

Comment: Your answer is a pointing to a different solution , It is not the solution of my problem .

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't understood your problem. On reading your question again, I figured out that you want to attach 4 binders with data inside a single adapter. If I understood it correctly this time, my earlier concept can be implemented to make your code independent of position restrictions.

Comment: You need to determine the type of binder for each position of data and then return the appropriate binder for the same just the way I showed for data.

Comment: I hope to have understood your question this time. In case I have failed again, please explain me your question once more.